# What happens during a hard reset?

Tags: boot, power

What exactly happens when you hold down the power button and perform a hard reset?

Does it involve only hardware, in the sense that it shuts down power and everything crashes in its current state?

Or is there software involved - the OS detects that you're holding down the power button and tries to save the applications' states to restore them later, so you're not completely screwed?

Also, I have noticed that after a hard reset, my computer takes longer to boot up. What is causing this? What is happening under the hood?

*Could somebody recommend good tags? The question isn't specific to an OS, though maybe it should be.*

Comment: Same as pulling the power cord, it cuts electricity to the pc mainboard. It takes longer to boot because it was not a clean shutdown, so windows has to load the last known good confiig from the registry and do a bunch of cleanup.

Comment: Pulling the cord leads to immediate power loss though. Why would the OS not detect that you're holding down the power button and attempt to perform a "safe" shutdown?

Comment: It is by design for windows to ignore it, sometimes you need to do this and don't want windows interfering. You can set windows to do a safe shut down by pressing the power button once (not holding), this can be done in power options.

Comment: Hard disks have enough power buffered in their electronics that they can park the head or do some other important stuff, like completing the write of the current block. Even though modern disks don't need to park heads anymore, the point that some residual power is left is still valid, and each device has a chance to do just a little something with it, whatever the driver tells it. Even the CPU can complete some final thousands of cycles until it really is dead.

Comment: @Moab In my experience computers actually boot up faster if you do a hard shutdown. Our organization's computers take about 70 seconds to boot up (Windows 7 Professional). Much of time waiting is at the Applying Group Policies local and group policies stage. If I do a hard shutdown, the PC in question boots in less than 15 seconds because it goes to the Windows Secure logon screen almost right away. That said, don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

What I believe happens is that pressing the reset button, causes the chipset on the motherboard to change the state of the reset pin on the CPU.

In this pdf for example: http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/4th-gen-core-family-desktop-vol-1-datasheet.pdf you can find information on "Reset and Miscellaneous Signals" on page 89.

You can see the CPU has a "RESET#" pin, which resets the platform and is driven by the Platform Controller Hub (PCH), which I think is basically the chipset. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Controller_Hub)

It might be possible that your motherboard does a more thorough Power-On-Self-Test (POST) after the reset button was pressed, so startup would take longer.

What exactly takes longer? The Windows loading screen or the BIOS operations before that?

Comment: I'm not quite sure the BIOS/motherboard would go through a more thorough POST after a hard reset because the hard reset would work very similarly to pulling the power cord or a power failure. I'm sure they'd be designed to POST as quickly as possible for the shortest time to get the OS booted. Yes, some BIOSes do a check but this is usually a check for hardware changes such as RAM, graphics/add-on cards and security mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

Pulling the cord is one way to shut down. If this is similar to pressing the power button for 10 seconds - no idea.

The difference with a normal shutdown is that the OS makes a note that shutdown was normal. When starting up, it looks for this, then sees it was not a normal shutdown, and then starts to do some tests, like a disk check. That takes more time.

When there is a power failure, it might result in a corrupt file, or even a corrupt partition. Some program might have been writing something to the harddisk, and halfway it stops. That file is probably corrupt. If that is an important file, it might corrupt the OS, or the filesystem. If you don't check this, and you have a corrupt filesystem, it's better to know it now than find out later.

I don't know how well harddisks handle problems like these, but I think they are pretty well protected against sudden loss of power.